# Ember Handlebars Confusion With Passing In Values

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I currently have a helper that looks like:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEq', function(a, b, opts) {
  if (a == b) {
    return opts.fn(this);
  } else {
    return opts.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

and in my template, I do

```
  GRAPH_TYPE: {{graphType}}
  {{#ifEq graphType "p_graph"}}
    TEST1
  {{else}}
    TEST2
  {{/ifEq}}
```

However, this displays

```
GRAPH_TYPE: p_graph TEST2
```

This leaves me confused as there should be an exact string match above.

So, I dug into the web inspector and noticed that the value of `a` in the Handlebars helper was of the value `graphType`. Why wasn't the value passed in and how do I ensure that it is passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register it as a *bound* helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('ifEq', function(a, b, opts) {
                         ^ like so
```

When you register a normal/basic helper, you're going to see the parameters passed in by string value as you're witnessing.

However, if you want the argument strings to be bound to properties in your template (which, in this case, you do), you need to use the function signature above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I am close but I am now running into `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.` on Ember 1.12

Comment: Shot in the dark - can you try using it as a subexpression, like: `{{#if (ifEq graphType "p_graph")}}`

Comment: Believe that would result in `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: It might, I'm not sure. I found the suggestion here and hoped it would work: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10295